# Layout control using FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, flowlayoutpanel

I want put a bunch of buttons at the top section of my form, and a SplitContainer right below these buttons. All these are done in the code (not thru the designer), so I can manage the number and text of the buttons dynamically. I reckon it is handy to put the button into a FlowLayoutPanel, so they can response with the flow feature when the form gets resized.

My question is how do I set up the SplitContainer layout settings (size, location, anchor, docking etc.), to make sure no matter how I resize the form, the SplitContainer is right below the buttons (no gap), and it fills up the rest of the form. Below is what I've done.

```
        this.Size = new Size(300, 400);

        string[] tags = new string[] { "action", "romance", "drama", "sci-fi", "horror" };
        FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        flp.Size = new Size(this.Width, 50);
        flp.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        flp.AutoSize = true;
        flp.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
        flp.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
        this.Controls.Add(flp);

        //flp.Resize += flp_Resize;

        foreach (string tag in tags)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = tag;
            flp.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

        SplitContainer sc = new SplitContainer();
        ListBox lb = new ListBox(); lb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; lb.Parent = sc.Panel1; lb.Items.Add("test");
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox(); pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; pb.Parent = sc.Panel2; pb.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        sc.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height-flp.Height);
        sc.Location = new Point(0, flp.Height);
        sc.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        this.Controls.Add(sc);
```

Here is the solution. Thanks to @Fabio.

```
        this.Size = new Size(300, 400);

        TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tlp.RowCount = 2;
        tlp.ColumnCount = 1;
        tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(tlp);            

        string[] tags = new string[] { "action", "romance", "drama", "sci-fi", "horror" };
        FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        flp.AutoSize = true;
        flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        flp.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
        flp.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
        tlp.Controls.Add(flp, 0, 0);

        foreach (string tag in tags)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = tag;
            flp.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

        SplitContainer sc = new SplitContainer();
        ListBox lb = new ListBox(); lb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; lb.Parent = sc.Panel1; lb.Items.Add("test");
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox(); pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; pb.Parent = sc.Panel2; pb.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        sc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tlp.Controls.Add(sc,0,1);
```

Comment: You can use `TableLayoutPanel`. In the first row put `FlowLayoutPanel` and in second row put your `SplitContainer.`

Comment: Thanks @Fabio. It works perfectly. I've updated the solution above.